# Program to overload < and > to compare two strings

Tags: c++, string, compare

Can anyone please help me out with 
Program to overload < and > to compare two strings.

Comment: Search the web and Stack Overflow using the words "C++ operator overloading example"

Comment: Strings already have overloaded `<` and `>` operators.

Comment: *"Can anyone please help me out with Program to overload < and > to compare two strings."* - No. You don't need help, it's already done.

Comment: I'd be happy to help if you show me what you've tried so far and what exactly you're having trouble with.  But this isn't a tutorial site -- we need you to try to figure it out on your own first.

Comment: And to add to the previous comments: you cannot legally do it, because you're not allowed to redefine parts of the standard language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different things that can be called strings in C++, `std::string` is the main one, and that already provides those operators. C-style null terminated strings are another, and string literals yet another. For the latter two, you cannot overload `operator<` or `operator>`, as you can only overload operators for user defined types.

Even if you were allowed to overload the operators, they would misbehave in obscure ways, as the set of associated namespaces for `const char*` (or `char*` for that matters) is empty, Argument Dependent Lookup would fail to find your overload if it finds a different operator earlier during regular lookup.

Comment: Thank you, As i am new to this language could you suggest me book to understand C++ from basic?

Comment: @Mohsin: There is already a [list of recommended books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) in this site.